# Vue removeListener within directive on destroy

Tags: vue.js, directive

I got an directive that i use for animating elements within the DOM, the directive looks like this:

```
Vue.directive('animate', {
    bind(el, binding) {
        let start = (binding.value)?binding.value.start:{y: 50, autoAlpha: 0};
        TweenMax.set(el, start);
    },
    inserted: function(el, binding) {
        let end = (binding.value)?binding.value.end:{y: 0, autoAlpha: 1};
        end.ease = Quart.easeOut;
        end.onComplete = () => {
            el.removeAttribute("style");
            el.classList.add("animation-done");
        };

        const f = function() {
            console.log("scrolling");
            if (InViewPort(el)) {
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', f);
                TweenMax.to(el, 1.5, end);
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('scroll', f);
        f();
    }
});
```

The directive is called within the component like this:

```
v-animate="{start: {y: 50, autoAlpha: 0}, end: {y: 0, autoAlpha: 1, delay: index * 0.5}}"
```

This gives me the flexibility i would like to have, only one problem. The event listener is within the `inserted` scope, and not available on the `unbind` hook.

Maybe directive isn't the way to go in Vue, does anybody have some advice how to handle this?

Comment: Create it as a property of `el`.

Comment: Thanks mate, should've taught of that :-)